# Laravel 5 : Nice way to generate table number?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I can generate table number like this in my views `index.blade.php`.

```
<?php $no = 1; ?>
@foreach($users as $user)
<td>{{ $no }}</td>
<td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
<?php $no++; ?>
@endforeach
```

and my controller is `UsersController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return view('admin.user.index')->withUsers($users);
}
```

Yes it work, but I think this not best practice and ugly to read since views only for interface not logic. I think something like pass data from controller or maybe you can answer with your ways.

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: What 's the purpose of the table number?

Comment: @mdamia ahh.. never mind about it, i don't know exactly the purpose, but usually i use it for table. thanks dude, i think i don't need table number anymore :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
@foreach($users as $index => $user)
  <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Note the `+1` since `$index` will start at `0`

Answer (score 4):

Before this approach, I was using the following way to generate table numbering.

#### Studentscontroller

```
$students = Student::orderBy( 'name', 'asc' )
                     ->paginate( 20 );

return view( 'students.index', [
    'students' => $students,
    'total' => $students->total(),
    'perPage' => $students->perPage(),
    'currentPage' => $students->currentPage()
] );
```

#### students/index.blade.php

```
<td class="text-center">{{ ( $currentPage - 1 ) * $perPage + $key + 1 }}</th>
```

Comment: Tnx so much! your comment was a hint for me!